# Puxar célula do excel na macro para enviar e-mails

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Na macro abaixo, eu tenho que atualizar na própria macro as informações para nos nos `Array`, seria possível puxar essas informações de uma célula no excel?

Por exemplo, Regios na coluna A, os `enderecosEmail` na coluna B

```
Sub CriarGraficoEnviarEmail()
    Dim regioes As Variant
    Dim enderecosEmail As Variant
    Dim enderecosCCEmail As Variant
    Dim assuntosEmail As Variant
    Dim nomeArquivoGrafico As String
    Dim i As Integer
Dim caminhosAnexos As Variant
    
    ' Inicialização das matrizes
    regioes = Array("Centro-Oeste", "Nordeste", "Sudeste")
    enderecosEmail = Array("email1@exemplo.com", "email2@exemplo.com", "email3@exemplo.com")
    enderecosCCEmail = Array("cc1@exemplo.com", "cc2@exemplo.com", "cc3@exemplo.com")
    assuntosEmail = Array("Assunto para Centro-Oeste", "Assunto para Nordeste", "Assunto para Sudeste")
    caminhosAnexos = Array("")
    
    ' Loop por cada região
    For i = LBound(regioes) To UBound(regioes)
        ' Filtra os dados pela região atual usando o Slicer
        Call FiltrarPorRegiao(CStr(regioes(i)))
        
        ' Criação do gráfico e exportação como imagem
        nomeArquivoGrafico = CriarEExportarGrafico("Planilha2", "A3:L55", i)
        
        ' Enviar e-mail com o gráfico anexado
        enviarEmail CStr(enderecosEmail(i)), CStr(assuntosEmail(i)), CStr(enderecosCCEmail(i)), CStr(nomeArquivoGrafico), CStr(caminhosAnexos(i))

    Next i
End Sub
```